# Azure APIM OpenAPI converting just a time string to date

Tags: openapi, apim

How do I display JUST a time value in OpenAPI 3.0? In Azure APIM I have the following

```
"shift1_start": "00:00:00"
```

When viewing the Developer Portal Documentation site it converts this to:

```
"shift1_start": "2023-05-12"
```

I tried the following: `"shift1_start": "'00:00:00'"` which output `"shift1_start": "'00:00:00'"` but I want the output to simply be `"shift1_start": "00:00:00"` (without the extra quotes). How can I achieve this? Does OpenAPI simply not support time stamps without the date component? My value stored in the database is not linked to a date and is just a timestamp.